# What is the advantage of organizing a free list in address order as opposed to LIFO order?

Tags: c, list, memory, malloc

I'm implementing malloc() in C, and right now my free list is maintained in LIFO order (i.e. newly freed blocks are added to the beginning of the list) and my allocator uses a first fit algorithm to search for free blocks of memory. My textbook mentions that maintaining the list in address order enjoys better memory utilization than a list in LIFO order in this situation, but I don't understand why and it doesn't explain. Eventually I'll implement a buddy system or something similar, but for now I just want to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Coalescing free blocks ("defragging") is easier if you have your free list sorted by address - joining two chunks into a larger chunk is essentially trivial then.